# svcutil omits the ServiceKnownType attribute from the generated interface proxy

Tags: wcf, svcutil.exe

I encountered a problem when I tried to implement the ServiceKnownType example from MSDN.
In the example they provide the following classes:

```
[DataContract()]
public class Widget
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Id;
    [DataMember]
    public string Catalog;
}

[DataContract()]
public class Machine : Widget
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Maker;
}
```

And the following interface:

```
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(Widget))]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(Machine))]
[ServiceContract()]
public interface ICatalog
{
    [OperationContract]
    Hashtable GetItems();
}
```

The problem is that when the proxy class is generated (using “Add Service Reference” / svcutil.exe), the “ServiceKnownType” attributes are omitted from the ICatalog proxy interface, resulting in getting an exception 
“The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: … 
Add the type corresponding to 'Widget' to the list of known types”
To solve this problem I have to manually add the service known attributes to the generated proxy interface, which is a very bad solution, since the code regenerates when I update the reference.
The interesting thing in all this situation, is that if the GetItems operation would return object instead of Hashtable, or getting an object as a parameter , then the problem would be solved, i.e.

```
[OperationContract]
object GetItems();
```

or

```
[OperationContract]
Hashtable GetItems(object obj);
```

results in presence of the “ServiceKnownType” attribute on ICatalog proxy interface.
Does anyone knows how to solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be a related [problem](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wcf/thread/4911eb56-d683-4445-bfd8-cdac3ae18ea9).

Did you try returning generic Dictionary of Widgets and putting `[KnownType(typeof(Machine))]` on Widget class?

Comment: I want it to work with ServiceKnownType and not with KnownType because  in my real-world scenario I can’t add an attribute on the “Widget” class since it’s located in a DLL I can’t change. I would appreciate any other solution for my scenario but I also want to know why the MSDN example doesn’t work

Answer (score 1):

I spent hours today on what, as best I can tell, is the exact same issue.  The solution for me was to use the AddGenericResolver method from IDesign's ServiceModelEx library.

NOTE: .NET 4.0 required as it uses [DataContractResolver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractresolver.aspx)

You can find it on [IDesign Downloads page](http://www.idesign.net/idesign/DesktopDefault.aspx?tabindex=5&tabid=11).

All I had to do in my case was add the following line of code:

```
Client.AddGenericResolver( typeof ( K2Source ) );
```

I hope this helps someone else out there save a few hours!

You can find more information in the book "Programming WCF Services: Mastering WCF and the Azure AppFabric Service Bus" by Juval Lowy

Answer (score 0):

Problem with ignored ServiceKnownType by svcutil is still here. My solution is add "known types" to client contract reference programmatically:

```
var client = new ServiceReferenceClient("clientEndpoint");
foreach (var o in client.Endpoint.Contract.Operations)
{
   o.KnownTypes.Add(typeof(MyType01));
   o.KnownTypes.Add(typeof(MyType02));
   o.KnownTypes.Add(typeof(MyType03));
}
```

It is not perfect solution (must be hard coded on client-side) but it works for me.